# Using a method in a Java class file

Tags: java, class, import

For class, I was given a .class file (no .java) and I need to create some JUnit tests of a method within that .class file. However, I'm not sure how to access the method. Incidentally, I'm using Eclipse.

I can import the file path, but it doesn't see the .class file. Meaning . . . the file is /class/file/utility/StringUtility.class.

import class.file.utility.*; (works)
import class.file.utility.StringUtility; (gives error)

I tried using the first import, but I have a similar problem when I try to access the class file. Meaning . . .

StringUtility newUtil = new StringUtility(); (gives error - it doesn't know what StringUtility is.

Any help would be appreciated.

SOLUTION BELOW   SOLUTION BELOW   SOLUTION BELOW

Since I am new to the forum I couldn't answer my own question. However, here is the solution. . .

Thank you everyone for your help! You pointed me in the right direction and I was able to sort out my problem. In case someone else runs into the same issue, here is how I solved it. Again, I'm using Eclipse (Indigo).

1) File -> Import -> Archive File

Hit next

Then I browsed to the correct directory and selected the zip file with my .class file.

This added the archive to my project.

2) Right click on the project. Select Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Under the "Libraries" tab, I selected "Add Class Folder". I then selected the folder I just added with the .class file.

I then entered StringUtil newUtil; and "Quick Fixed" the import to the code.

Hopefully, this will spare someone the four hours it took me to sort it out. :)

Again, thank you everyone for your comments. As I mentioned, they were helpful.

Comment: Are you positive that the class is on your classpath? Because if it was, and you wrote `StringUtility newUtil`, and then used Quick Fix, Import, or Organize Imports in Eclipse, it would have figured out the necessary import. What steps did you take to configure the Java Build Path so that this class is on the classpath?

Comment: *"Any help would be appreciated."* Any question would be useful.  BTW - don't forget to add the homework tag to homework questions.

Comment: I used javap as suggested in one of the answers to verify the correct path (you were right class wasn't in the path). I tried a couple of things. The first is I created a package structure that matched what was displayed from the javap (file.utility). I can import that package structure, but I still get an error with file.utility.StringUtility. It says "the import file.utility.StringUtility cannot be resolved". my import statement is: import file.utility.StringUtility.  I also tried changing the build directory by "adding a folder", but same issue.

Comment: Does it matter that it is a .class file and not a .java file?

Comment: Also, the Quik Fix, Import and Organize Imports don't seem to work. Probably because it cannot resolve the StrungUtility.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command line, you can run the `javap` command to see what's inside the class file and get your bearings. For example, if the file you received is called `Test.class` type this in the command prompt in the directory where the file is actually located:

```
javap Test
```

The above will allow you to find out the correct package for importing the class, and to see the method signatures in the class file.

Also, I suspect that the right import statement should be:

```
import file.utility.StringUtility
```

That is, assuming that your own classes are located in the correct package.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about javap. I wasn't familiar with that.

Comment: @user538335 give it a try, and if this or any other answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it as correct (click the check mark to its left)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the actual package of the class is `file.utility`, which means you should add the `class` folder to the build path of your test project, and adjust your imports accordingly.